# Is it possible to list the keymaps available on Ubuntu 14.04? And why is the behavior different in login shell and non-login shell?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard-layout

Is it possible to list the available keymaps to `loadkeys` or `setxkbmap` command under 14.04? I really wonder how many options there are, why `setxkbmap` does not work on login shell and why `loadkeys` does not work on GUI with X enabled.

Answer (score 1):

`loadkeys` loads a keyboard map into a virtual console. It has nothing to do with X.

In Ubuntu the preferred way of setting up the console is to use [`setupcon`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man1/setupcon.1.html). See [`man 5 keyboard`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/zesty/en/man5/keyboard.5.html).

`setxkbmap` loads a keyboard map in the X server. It has nothing to do with virtual consoles. I don't understand what's the relationship between `setxkbmap` and a login shell or non-login shell. The shell is not a graphical application.

Comment: `loadkeys` command does not work when X is running and it was even written in the output of one of the commands. I used the login, non-login shell to distinguish between pseudo terminals accessed by keystrokes and the terminal emulator. Running `less /usr/share/X11/xkb/rules/xorg.lst` provided information about the available keyboard layouts; however, the command `man 5 keyboard` returns nothing.

Comment: I provided a link. `loadkeys` is supposed to work in a virtual console, not in X.

Comment: I clicked on the link, but thought the command should open the relevant manual page when executed in the terminal.

Comment: @Vesnog: It should, and it does on 16.04. I no longer have a working 14.04 installation.

Comment: Strange does it suggest that something is missing with my Ubuntu 14.04 installation?